# Defining methods for each enum in a separate file

Tags: java, enums

I'm looking for a way to be able to define a method for each enum instance. We all know about the code construction at the bottom of this page.

The difference I'm looking for is to be able to define one or more abstract methods for each enum in a separate file that is verified compile-time. Meaning if someone were to add another enum instance I would get a compile-time error and not a run-time error which is what I get with the construction at the bottom of this page.

The reason for the request is that in some code I'm looking at there are many methods that should be defined per enum but are really unrelated to the enum definition so I'd like to place them in separate files but not lose the benefits of the "standard" way of solving this.

```
public enum MyEnum {
X {
    public void calc(Outer o) {
        // do something
    }
},
Y {
    public void calc(Outer o) {
        // do something
    }
};

// abstract method
abstract void calc(Outer o);
```

}

Comment: Don't forget enums are object, so if I translate what you are saying is : I want to define some methods about an object outside of this object definition. This is definitely an antipattern of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define methods for classes outside of a class!

You could define a callback interface that each enum instance had to have an instance of:

```
public interface MyEnumCallback {
  doStuff(final Outer o)
}
```

Then your enum would look something like

```
public enum MyEnum {
  X(new XCallback()),
  Y(new YCallbaxk());

  private final MyEnumCallback callback;

  public MyEnum(final MyEnumCallback callback) {
     this.callback = callback;
  }

  public <Whatever> call(final Outer o) {
     callback.doStuff(o);
  }
}
```

This separates your `Enum` from the methods as you wanted - it would also throw a compile time error if someone didn't provide an implementation of `MyEnumCallback` to the constructor of the `Enum` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the folowing code:

```
interface Delegate{
    void calc();
}

enum TestEnum {

    EnumValue1(new Delegate() {
        @Override
        public void calc() {

        }
    }),

    EnumValue2(new Delegate() {
        @Override
        public void calc() {

        }
    });

    private Delegate delegate;

    TestEnum(Delegate d){
        this.delegate = d;
    }

    public Delegate getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main() {
        TestEnum.EnumValue1.getDelegate().calc();
        TestEnum.EnumValue2.getDelegate().calc();
    }
}
```